# What's the application of doubly-stochastic matrices in engineering?

Tags: matrices, stochastic-matrices, hidden-markov-models

Today I learned the existence of such matrix .
[wolframe](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoublyStochasticMatrix.html)

This is indeed a very interesting thing. I am wondering if there is any realworld application of such matrix.

It seems that this matrix has application in HMM hidden markov model

Comment: [Birkhoff polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff_polytope): https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/4805/53274

Comment: The [Relative Gain Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_Gain_Array) is used in Control Engineering. All of its row and columns sum to one. However since it contains both positive _and negative_ elements, it might not meet a strict definition of stochastic.